How can I link an object file in a subdirectory to a kernel module?
I have a directory structure that looks like the following (for practical reasons, I'll simplify the structure of my project):
.
|__ subdir
|  |__ subdir.c
|  |__ Makefile
|
|__ mymodule.c
|__ Makefile

I want to build a kernel module mymodule.ko by linking mymodule.o and subdir.o. I understand that I can achieve something like this with the following Makefile:
# Root Makefile
obj-m := mymodule.o

mymodule-y := subdir/subdir.o


all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$$PWD modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$$PWD clean

However, I want to compile the source files in subdir with specific compilation flags, in this case -msse. By adding the source file as mymodule-y += subdir/subdir.o, Kbuild builds it with the default flags, and I get the error:
error: SSE register return with SSE disabled

This is why I decided compile it with a separate Makefile. It looks like the following.
# Subdir Makefile
obj-m := subdir.o

ccflags-y += -msse


all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$$PWD modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$$PWD clean

I'm not convinced about using module recipes for this sub-Makefile, but I don't see any other way to build these source files with Kbuild. I am assuming that any code that goes to the kernel must be built through Kbuild. By using module recipes, the compiler complains about the source file not having a MODULE_LICENSE(), because of course, it is not a module. However, if I run make, the object files do get created.
After this, I tried including the precompiled object files in subdir renaming them subdir.o_shipped. But I still get the SSE register return with SSE disabled error.
I have found similar questions about linking precompiled objects and objects in subdirectories to a kernel module (1, 2) , but I haven't found a question that includes compiling some source files with specific flags and then linking them to a kernel module's source that is compiled with the default flags. Any help would be appreciated :)

You can’t enable SSE for only one module, IIRC (because of the context switching and state save-restore mechanism). Hence you need to enable it for the entirety re kernel.

In the past I have compiled a kernel in which I added a subdirectory that had the -msse specified in the Makefile. From the outermost Makefiles, I'd just indicate Kbuild to go through my subdirectory. So I effectively isolated the -msse to compilation units inside a subdirectory when compiling the kernel source (at least I believe so since it compiled it and it seemed to work), and wrapped calls to files in the subdirectory with the the kernel_fpu_...() routines (I was working on x86). I want to do something similar when compiling a kernel module, are you saying that can't be done?
